# react component renders before sets the data as a prop, therefore it give me undefined value

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

im using react with react-redux and react-router. im working on my blog, in which i have a component with shows list of posts. so everything is working fine but when i get post.id in component it gives me undefined. on the other hand posts are passing to component from container.
please look into my code.

```
//home_container.js

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { show } from './actions'
import HomeComponent from './home_component'


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
     posts: state.posts.data
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
     actions:{
       showPosts: (page,limit) => {
        show(dispatch,page,limit)
      }
    }


  }
}

const HomeContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HomeComponent)

export default HomeContainer
```

//home_component.js file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Style from './styles.css'
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import {  Link } from 'react-router'

require('rc-pagination/assets/index.css');
const Pagination = require('rc-pagination');
const style = {
  height: "100%",
  margin: 10,
  padding: 10,
  display: 'inline-block',
};


var Detail = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div >
         <div className="row">


             <div >

               <p>{this.props.post?this.props.post.body.substr(1,600):''}</p>
              {this.props.post?
               <span style={{"float":"right"}}>
                  <Link to={`/posts/${this.props.post.id}`}>
                    <FlatButton
                        label="Ready more"
                        labelPosition="before"
                        primary={true}
                    />
                  </Link>
                </span>
              :''}  
             </div>

         </div> 
      </div>
    )
  }
});

class Index extends Component {

  getChildContext() {
      return { muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme) };
 }

componentDidMount(){
  this.props.actions.showPosts(1,5)
}

  render() {
    return (
        <div >


        {this.props.posts.map((post,i) =>
         <div className="row" key={i}> 
           <Paper 
           style={style} 
           zDepth={0} 
           children={<Detail post={post}/>}
           />

        )} 


        </div>  
    );
  }

}
 Index.childContextTypes = {
      muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
 };

export default Index;
```

i already check through react-redux inspector. i have posts in posts props of this component, which are sets by container through react redux.
so problem is in the following part of above code.

```
 <Link to={`/posts/${this.props.post.id}`}>
                        <FlatButton
                            label="Ready more"
                            labelPosition="before"
                            primary={true}
                        />
</Link>
```

Link to tag of react router generate url in this form posts/undefined. because it is considering that post.id is undefined. on the other hand each post have id property and i also checked it through inspection of  posts objects.

so problem is in this line `this.props.post.id`

Comment: in abowe code is `this.props.post.body` defined ? and `this.props.post.id` is undefined ?

Comment: yeah. this.props.post.body return correct value and its defined. and this.props.post.id is undefined (only when i use with LINK to helper of react router) .  when i just render this.props.id it shows id on page.

Comment: Try defining the link string outside of the return value of `render`. So, have a line after `render(): function() {` (which, by the way, should just be `render() {` that has `const postId = this.props.post.id || null;` and try using `postId` in your `Link` tag's `to` attribute instead.